# Entity Framework max ID

Tags: entity-framework

In my table, I have several thousands of records. This table stores records of books. Let´s say, some books are special, so they are given an ID greater than 1500000. Other books, which are not special have classicaly IDs from 1 - 15879 (or whatever lesser than 1500000).

Now, I want to get the biggest ID of non-special book, using Entity Framework.

Comment: Please, make your question clearer (table with books and wor[kd]books?). In general: `context.Books.Max(b => b.Id);`.

Comment: Edited, hopefully it is comprehendible now.

Comment: One advice: don't use surrogate key values to implement business logic. Introduce a type field of sorts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter your less that 1500000 books and get the `Max()` for that:

```
context.Books.Where(b => b.Id < 1500000).Max(b => b.Id);
```